# Wordpress: php.ini, wp-config.php changes not taking effect

Tags: php, wordpress, html, web-hosting

I need to increase the php max upload limit and post max limit, when i add it in php.ini and saved through ftp, but do not taking any effect.

And tried in wp-config, htaccess and in renamed the php.ini into php5.ini, I failed.. Any one please help, host support guys are worst when just ask help from the them.

Comment: Different hosting platforms have different ways to allow you to configure stuff like this (or restrict you from doing it altogether.) We here have no idea what setup your hoster is using, so asking their support directly is your best option.

Comment: Current hosting is godaddy, php v5.6, and there always getting ram full, when i save any pages in wordpress and for sometime website wont connect

Comment: Well that sounds like you have an issue with the `memory_limit` setting, rather than the two you mentioned.

Comment: i just checked through cpanel, gottachaa,, thank you cbroe

Comment: That one works fine, and i have another problem too when i saving pages in wordpress webpage getting error and [ram memory full]. OPS!!!! It before also happened, I thought its because of memory limit issues, but it not, i will open a new thread for it, please contribute. @CBroe

Answer (score 0):

Friends, I got the solution for this with easy steps from other thread:
[alternate way tried from cpanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32277542/how-can-i-increase-upload-file-size-on-godaddy-shared-hosting-with-cpanel)

Thank you for you skills shared with me, that skilled very well.